# I'm trying to suppress the UAC prompt using the COM Moniker

Tags: c, winapi, com, elevation

Windows explorer asks for UAC elevation when trying to copy files to certain locations, like `system32`. When clicking continue, elevation occurs in the background when the current UAC strictness level is set to the second to last value (Notify only when try to make changes to my computer (default)).

I have seen other programs (that are not digitally signed) use `CoGetObject` to create an elevated `IFileOperation.` I'm trying to do this in my application, but UAC keeps on prompting. Yes, the code works, but I want to get the same silent result the 3rd party program and Windows Explorer get when acquiring an elevated `IFileOperation.` This is my code so far. It is C not C++.

```
CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
BIND_OPTS3 ops = {0};

//Random sized buffer large enough to hold values, THIS IS ONLY FOR TESTING!!
WCHAR clsidName[210],
    monikerName[500];

StringFromGUID2(&CLSID_FileOperation, clsidName, sizeof(clsidName) / sizeof(WCHAR));

StringCchPrintfW(monikerName, sizeof(monikerName) / sizeof(WCHAR), L"Elevation:Administrator!new:%s", clsidName);

ops.dwClassContext = CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER;
ops.cbStruct = sizeof(BIND_OPTS3);
IFileOperation ppv;
HRESULT hr = CoGetObject(monikerName, &ops, &IID_IFileOperation, &ppv);
```

Comment: Microsoft have added their own software to a whitelist that's exempt from prompting, no one else is as fortunate.

Comment: You cannot suppress UAC. If you could, there would be no point in UAC at all.